# How to convert excel file to CSV using SSIS Script or Azure Logic apps task from One Azure blob container to another

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-logic-apps

Receiving an excel file every day with one sheet(Sheet name will be the different every time) and that will be stored in Azure Blob container and is there any possibility to convert the excel to CSV either by using SSIS script Task or Azure Logic Apps.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways we can do that.

With Logic app, you could ref the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/89b6f233-00ae-4561-9126-77325d64d532/convert-excel-to-csv-on-azure-blob-storage-through-logic-app):

Converting should be pretty easy. On high level, you can do following:

1. Use [Excel connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-excel) to read into the content of the excel file
2. Use [Data Operations - Create CSV Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-csv-table-action) to create a CSV format populated with dynamic data from step #1
3. Use [Azure Blob Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) to create and save the new csv file on the blob storage

Since the excel is stored in Blob Storage, I would suggest you use [Data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage), it supports [Excel file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel) directly:

Create the Source dataset:
[image]

Create Sink dataset: set the new csv file name:
[image]

Copy active overview:
[image]

It works well and very easy and directly:
[image]

Comment: I am using Excel Connector and not sure which activity I should use under Excel connector. I tried with all Excel activities it is asking me to give one drive location. But my actual file is there in Blob location. I don't think using excel connector is the right option here?

Comment: Hi @KallipudiSudheer,  Do you think about use Data Factory? It can be more easier. I will show you the example.

Comment: Hi Leon, thank you for your help.. Unfortunately I cannot provide the sheet name while creating excel source linked service because it is dynamic.